# Table of Contents not dynamically updating

Tags: table-of-contents

This is the code I am using (along with the `datenumber` package) to create subsection titles that include an increasing date.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\mysubsectiontitle{Week of \StrLeft{\datemonthname}{3}. \thedateday, \thedateyear}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{\subsection{\mysubsectiontitle #1}}
```

The section titles do increase, but the table of contents display the same date across.

Subsections:

[image]

[image]

TOC:

[image]

I am also getting a lot of warnings in the form "Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode)."

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\setdatenumber{2024}{02}{26}

\newcommand{\mysectiontitle}{\datemonthname~\thedateyear}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\section{\mysectiontitle #1}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mysubsectiontitle{Week of \StrLeft{\datemonthname}{3}. \thedateday, \thedateyear}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{\subsection{\mysubsectiontitle #1}}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\mysection{}

\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}

\mysection{}

\end{document}
```

The above covers the relevant code. Output:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I can get rid of the warnings mentioned above by surrounding the `\StrLeft{\datemonthname}{3}` with `\texorpdfstring{}{}`, but that does not fix the Table of Contents not updating correctly problem.

Comment: Why don't you show usable code? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: @MS-SPO Is that good?

Comment: Without having tried it: yes. Thank you

Comment: If you take a look in the `.toc` file you'll see what the problem is, `\mysubsectiontitle` is never expanded before the data is written to the toc file (due to it being robust). The main problem seems to be `\StrLeft{\datemonthname}{3}` is that is removed and `\mysubsectiontitle` is a normal `\newcommand` it does work.

Comment: Also note that your three letter abbreviation is wrong for May.

Comment: Just for etiquette @MikeSmith, the question space should be reserved for questions only and the answer space for answers, editing the answer into your question was done with the best intentions and I know you are new but please don't do that, it clutters up the questions :) I've +1 to counteract your -1 question score that someone probably gave you for that, hope you ask more questions here :) Feel free to clean your question up like you did in your edit but don't put an answer in it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure why `\StrLeft` is so bad here. But I chose a different route.
By doing the month list manually we can ensure that there are no abbreviation dot after May.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\setdatenumber{2024}{02}{26}
\newcommand\AbrevMonth{%
  \ifcase\value{datemonth}%
  \or Jan.%
  \or Feb.%
  \or Mar.%
  \or Apr.%
  \or May%
  \or Jun.%
  \or Jul.%
  \or Aug.%
  \or Sep.%
  \or Oct.%
  \or Nov.%
  \or Dec.%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand{\mysectiontitle}{\datemonthname~\thedateyear}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\section{\mysectiontitle #1}}

\newcommand\mysubsectiontitle{Week of \AbrevMonth\ \thedateday, \thedateyear}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{\subsection{\mysubsectiontitle}}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\mysection{}

\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}
\nextdate
\mysubsection{}

\mysection{}

\end{document}
```